# Can't send post request to authenticate user in react & redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have implemented all of actions and want to call that action with username and password parameters to authenticate user in form.But when I click submit no request is being sended and nothing happens.Code is a little bit long so I'm gonna cut the main part.

actions.js

```
const authStart = () => {
  return {
    type: "AUTH_START",
  };
};

const authSucceed = (token) => {
  return {
    type: "AUTH_SUCCESS",
    payload: token,
  };
};

const authFailed = (error) => {
  return {
    type: "AUTH_FAILED",
    payload: error,
  };
};

export const authLogin = (username, password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(authStart());
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const token = res.data.key;
        dispatch(authSucceed(token));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(authFailed(err));
      });
  };
};
```

SignIn.js

```
const SignIn = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  // const [username,setUsername] = useState("")
  // const [password,setPassword] = useState("")

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onAuth(username,password)
    setUsername("");
    setPassword("");
    
    
  };
  
  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="username"
            label="Username"
            name="username"
            autoComplete="username"
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link to="/signup" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state.Auth
    
  
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onAuth: (username,password) => {authLogin(username,password)}
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn);
```

I'll be grateful if you help me out with this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the way your code is setup, `authLogin` returns a function which takes `dispatch` as a param, so you probably need to do:

```
onAuth: (username,password) => {authLogin(username,password)(dispatch)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bindActionCreators() as well to return the dispatch function, in the following way:-

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(authLogin(username,password), dispatch)
  }
}
```

If you want another way to do the same, you could refer to the link below.
https://blog.logrocket.com/react-redux-connect-when-and-how-to-use-it-f2a1edab2013/